# how to pass Xpath value in javascript function

Tags: asp.net, xpath, onclientclick

here my code that gives error-

```
OnClientClick='javascript:DragRevId(<%# XPath("ReservationId") %>);return false;'
```

Comment: It looks like this is not about an XPath expression but how to use an XPath engine in ASP.Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably has something to do with the fact that XPath's use the '\' character. You'll need to escape that character if you want to use it with javascript.

Example:
Node\Child --> Node\\Child

So, within ASP, do a String.Replace('\', "\\"); or something similar.

If this doesn't work you might want to consider posting the error that is thrown, and specifying if it is an ASP.Net error or a Javascript error.